# how i can build app in 2g phone using 3gs frameworks

Tags: iphone, frameworks, sdk, ios, barcode-scanner

I am developing one application which need scanning component, I have application ready but when I build it in 2g phone with os version 3.1.3, application gives me error.
I have weak linked those framework which are not in 2g. 
ERROR: Not Enough Frames In Stack
Do advice thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing what errors you're getting, or which part of the code it's crashing on (assuming its a crash this mysterious 'error'), we can't begin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you have 2 options:

1. Always check existence of such API call by probing with [respondToSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) message
2. Check iOS version level by calling [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) and avoid incompatible calls by using good old if...else... statements

Comment: Thanks you all, actually as and when my application starts it shows me this error... even first splash screen is also not loading... please tell me where i can check fot respondToSelector message.???

Comment: Try "divide and conquer" approach. Leave basic app skeleton without your own added logic. See if it works on your phone.